# ErrorHandling React Router v6 is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, vite

I tried to handle any errors occured that breaks my application using React Router Dom - ErrorHandling. But seems like it's not working. What am I missing in this code?

My App Code

```
import ErrorHandling from "./ErrorHandling"

// prettier-ignore
export default memo(function AppLayout() {
  const location = useLocation()
  return (
    <>
      <Toaster />
      <AnimatePresence mode="wait" initial={false}>
        <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
          <Route path={`/`} element={<AppLayer><Navigate to={`/v3/dashboard`} /></AppLayer>}/>
          <Route path={`/v3/`} element={<AppLayer><Navigate to={`/v3/dashboard`} /></AppLayer>}/>
          <Route path={`/v3`} element={<AppLayer></AppLayer>} errorElement={<ErrorHandling/>}>
            <Route path={`login`} element={<Login />} />
```

My App Layer

```
export const dashboardContext = createContext()

// prettier-ignore
export default function AppLayer({children}) {

  // dashboard context
  const [data, setData] = useState(false)

  // check if user is login
  if (!AuthHelpers.is_user_login()) window.location.href = "/v3/login"

  return (
    <dashboardContext.Provider value={{data, setData}}>
      <AppData>
        <Outlet />
      </AppData>
    </dashboardContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

My Error Handling Component

```
import React from "react"
import {useRouteError} from "react-router-dom"

export default function ErrorHandling() {
  const error = useRouteError()
  console.log(error)
  return (
    <div className="text-center w-screen h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-neutral-70">
      <h1 className="text-48">Error!</h1>
      <p className="text-24">Something's Wrong.</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

#### I expect the errors to be redirected to ErrorElement instead of blank white page.

Comment: What error element/boundary are you referring to? Can you [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve], and clarify what the issue is? Also, be aware that declaring React components inside other React components is a bit of a React anti-pattern.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, Thanks for your reply. I edited my questions above and including some of the codes that might clarify the ErrorHandling components. To be detail, if something happens in the child route of `<Route path={"/v3"} element={<AppLayer></AppLayer>} errorElement={<ErrorHandling/>}>`, it's not being redirected to the ErrorHandling components.

Comment: I hope you are aware that the route `errorElement` prop only works in Data routers. Using them in a regular router has no effect, which is likely why you are struggling to get it to work. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/error-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they say in [the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/error-element),

> This feature only works if using a data router, see [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)

but you are using it in a `BrowserRouter`, so it won't work.